# Decision split always leads to same path when contact is injected twice

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I created a journey using a Salesforce Data Event as entry event, that is triggered on creation of an instance of a custom object. One contact should be able to re-entry this journey at any time as a contact can be linked to many instances of the custom object triggering the journey. So in Contact Builder the data extension of the entry event is linked to the Contact using a one-to-many relationship and the journey re-entry settings are also set accordingly.

I selected contact data for the decision split and the value is evaluated correctly for the first journey injection of every unique contact. However, if a contact enters the journey again, it follows the path of the first time it has been injected, no matter which value is set in the field evaluated by the decision split for the following entries.

Is there a workaround for this? Is further configuration in contact builder needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching the decision split to using event data after the first contact entered the journey I got an error that the used expression of the decision split is invalid.

But I just figured out how to solve this. First I added another relationship in Contact Builder to connect the salesforce data event's data extension to the synchronized custom object that triggers the event. In this case I used a one-to-one relationship via the salesforce id of the custom object. Then I switched from using contact data to event data in the decision split, which didn't work without the added relationship.

**Summary**

1. Added 1-to-1 relationship between sf-data-event-DE and the synchronized custom object DE
2. Reconfigured decision split to using event data